# Excel query for 2 workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have 2 worksheets open.

What I need to know is if I populate cell A1 in worksheet 1 with £500, I need cell A1 in worksheet 2 to automatically populate with the number 1.
Then when I input £500 again in B2 in worksheet 1, again I need cell B2 in worksheet to automatically populate with the number 1.

Is it the 'IF' value I need to use?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This, This is checking below logic;

If value in sheet1,A1 cell is equal to 5000 then print 1.

`=IF(Sheet1!A1=5000,1,0)`